# how to access cloudwatch logs cross account continously

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, prometheus

**Current Situation**
I am in process to create monitoring system for my AWS account with prometheus and grafana. it is able to display results from same AWS account.

**Problem Statement**
I want to pull cloudwatch metrics from other AWS account to centralized logging system.

**Things i tried**
As per my understanding we can use IAM cross account feature  to access data present in other AWS account. i found some  AWS documentation  online but it is mainly for non programmetic user.

[https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html] 
and 
 [https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_roles_common-scenarios_aws-accounts.html]

this require user to login to AWS web console and switch role manually. again tokan available is only for one hour by default

does AWS provide some way to fetch data continously for programmetic user.

Comment: You can use the Security Token Service https://docs.aws.amazon.com/STS/latest/APIReference/Welcome.html to assume a cross-account role and get back temporary credentials as long as the IAM permissions for the source principle as well as the target role allow it. The AWS SDKs make use of this when you specify a role in your `~/.aws/config`, e.g. python's docs https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/configuration.html#assume-role-provider

Comment: You mention both CloudWatch Logs and CloudWatch Metrics.   Which one are you wanting as these require different solutions.  Also, do you own all the AWS accounts or are some of these customer accounts?